# 2D array elements replaced with interval indices

Tags: python, arrays, indexing, intervals

Say you had an array of random elements in Python in the range N-M e.g.

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)

a_2d_array = np.random.uniform(0,100,(2,2))
```

And say you had some interval ranges starting at X and finishing at Y e.g.

`intervals` = [0-10] , [10-20] , [20-30] ... [90-100]

Is there an efficient way of replacing the elements of `a_2d_array` with the index of `intervals` within which the elements lie.

e.g:

```
print(a)

[[54.88135039 71.51893664]
 [60.27633761 54.4883183 ]]
```

would be replaced by:

```
[[4 7]
 [6 5]]
```

where, for clarity, element 0 of `a` falls into the 4th element of `intervals` etc.

There may be a way to do this using [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Interval.html) as I know it has interval functionality but I can't see a fast way of doing it.

Note that this should work for any set of intervals (i.e. the intervals can start with any real number whether positive or negative and non-zero).

Many thanks in advance for any help on this!

Edit:

Example solutions that I have tried:

One can simply use:

```
a = np.random.uniform(-100,100,(2,2))

print(a) 
array([[-20.8722065 ,  30.65764508],
       [ 12.03883227, -84.36615283]])

step_size = 10
a//10
array([[-3.,  3.],
   [ 1., -9.]])
```

So one need only know the `step_size` in this example.

Comment: The short answer to "Is there an efficient way of replacing the elements of `a_2d_array` with the index of `intervals` within which the elements lie" is yes. Can you provide some examples of what you have tried and what does not work?

Comment: I've added in the example I have so far tried. I don't know if it's the most efficient but it is decoupled from an explicit interval list and one would require knowledge of the minimum interval in order to account for negative indices as shown in the example above.